# Breaking TypeScript NPM package into multiple files without exposing internal components

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I have an NPM package written in TypeScript which is designd to work with Node.js applications. I have classes in this package which have methods that are internal use only, although I cannot mark them as private because they are used by other components within the package. To solve this problem, I do not export the class from the project, and when I return an instance of the class to the caller, I type cast it as an interface which only has the publicly accessible methods.

This works fine, but if I want to break my project into smaller files, how can I do this without being forced to export my classes, and risk the misuse of my NPM module?

Here is a simplified example of what I am trying to do:

File: internal.ts

```
// Can I make this class not publicly accessible?
export class InternalClass {
    constructor() {

    }

    public sharedMethod(): void {
        // Accessible to users of the package
    }

    public protectedMethod(): void {
        // Only for use within the package
    }
}
```

File: external.ts

```
import { InternalClass } from "./internal";

export interface ExternalInterface {
    sharedMethod(): void;
    // protectedMethod is not available outside the package
}

export function makeInterface(): ExternalInterface {
    return new InternalClass();
}
```

Any ideas for how to do this well would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way I do this is by controlling what exactly gets exposed by the npm package.

For example if my `package.json` looks like this:

```
{
  ....
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "typings": "typings/index.d.ts",
  ....
}
```

then in the corresponding `index.ts` I can manually control what will be exposed (exported) as part of the package.

```
export * from "./lib/Helper";
export * from "./lib/Log";

import * as M from "./lib/Maps";
export {M as Maps};
```

If I have module/class that I do not want to be accessible "outside" - I simply do not export it as part of `index.ts` or its referenced children. This does not prohibit me though to import and use it internally in the same package.

Comment: Thanks. This looks like it should do the trick. I will comment again when I have been able to try implementing this.

Comment: When I try this approach, I find that I still need to include the typings files from the internal stuff, since index.d.ts does not itself contain these types, instead referencing the other typings files. As a result, users can import the internal types by referencing the files directly. For example:
`import { InternalClass } from "my-npm-module/internal.d.ts"`

Comment: I was able to overcome this problem by splitting all my code into public / private files and only include the public type definition files in the NPM package. Since the type definition files were then not included for the private files, those ones could not be imported in TypeScript. Not exactly air-tight, but better than having all my code in a single file.

Comment: @Baudzilla Don't you have to include all the files (both internal and public) from the dist folder in the npm package.json files list? What stops library users from importing from `/dist/internal`? (curious as I'm trying to solve the same problem)